# CSS / Special Browsers: 'hidden' elements are seen by some user (in some Browser)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

This is a question for specialists!

I have a form with some honeypot fields. The spam mechanic (not only honeypot fields) works proper: all spam mails are blocked. So far so good ...

But sometimes there are mails blocked as spam which are sended by real humans. In the spam report I see, that this special users fill out honeypot fields they should not be able to see. But however ... obviously they can see the fields ... The fields are hidden by very old, traditional and reliable css technique ... I had supposed up to now.

I could identify two browser engines (up to know):

Blink
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36

Android 8.0 (Samsung)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SAMSUNG SM-T580) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/13.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36

My question is about if anyone know that phenomenon and how this strange behavior could bee ...

Do they deactivate scripts (but deactivating css is not a typicla bowser feature)?
Do they have a special view modes in the browser?
Is that phenomenon known on other browsers?
...

Unfortunately I had not chance to check the view in the named Browser-Engines ... all checks in the modern browser including old IE and modern Android and Safari versions had been OK.

---

HTML for the fields in the form ist:

````
.pform-wrapper [data-default="no name"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -90000000px;
}

.pform-wrapper [data-default="no phone"] {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
<div class="pform-wrapper"><form>
           <p class="pform-el" data-default="no name">
          <label>Vorname:<br />
            <span class="first-name">
               <input
                type="text"
                name="first-name"
                value=""
                size="40"
                placeholder="Vorname" />
            </span><br />
          </label>
        </p>
   
        <p class="pform-el" data-default="no phone">
          <label>Telefon:<br />
            <span class="phone">
              <input type="text"  name="phone" value="" size="40"
                placeholder="Telefonnummer" />
               
               
               
             </span><br />
          </label>
        </p>
  
</form></div>
```
````

Short remark: the quesiton is more about to learn about the why and less to find a solution (that is still on progress).

Bes regards for every hint
Brebber

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to be nothing to do with the browser engine.

Moving content off screen without setting it to `display: none` was a common technique used to add text labels that were visible only to screen reader users when the visible label was expressed in the form of a background image.

It's possible you have users who depend on such software.

Comment: Thx for your Answer. No. There is no need and technique for screenreaders on that page. The script has been developed to block robots from using forms. Because it is an individual (not common known) script/technique it works proper since years now. Moving out the fields without using 'display:none' (as well as the other used zero-height technique) is used to make honeypot fields only visible to spam robots. Now I saw first time that are (very) few human user obviously see that 'hidden' fields and I wonder how and on what browsers that could be on such a common proved css technique...

Comment: @Brebber — Why is there no need for people to use screen readers on that page? Have you forbidden blind people from using it? If so, you might want to check your local accessibility laws.

Comment: "Now I saw first time that are (very) few human user obviously see that 'hidden' fields and I wonder how and on what browsers that could be on such a common proved css technique" — As I said in this answer: People using screen readers.

Comment: @Qentin --- Thx for pressing your statement. Indeed it seems I have been to fast. Sorry for that. Indeed in that project no code had been used for screen readers up to now. But I changed the form plugin ... and indeed there is screenreader code included now ... so I will chek that as possible reason ... And indeed it is a very good hint for further practise in every case ... Testing that will take some time as I don't have practice with screenreader technique. I suppose there is no easy attribute I can set to a wrapper to hide the whole form from screenreaders without changing css?

Comment: Well ... seems attribute ```aria-hidden="true"``` to a simple wrapper is the magic one in this case as I understand it ... (Feedback always is welcome.) Once more thx for the hint. Test is running and but will take some time ...